# Having password field optional only when editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, and I have this issue.
So, my model have a password attribute, when creating should be required, but when editing it should be optional, so you only change the password if you want to, but I don't know how to let it be optional if I mark it with required in the model. What should I do?

The best solution is to have a different view for changing the password?

I appreciate your help, thanks!

```
[Required]
[ValidatePasswordLength]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either create a separate view model, or in your controller code check if its there, if not use ModelState.AddError("fieldName", "PAssword is required")